# Trying to Check My Work but How to Print()?

Tags: sorting, printing, lua, lua-table

I am trying to practice `table.sort`ing and tables in general.  I am taking the table `t{}` below and `table.sort` it by the numerical value of each of the names.  I am having problems printing up the original table `t{}` once it has been sorted into `a{}` (I am trying to print `a{}` just to clear that up).  Where would I place the `print (`*and what code?*`)` into code like this?

Sorry for the rookie, beginner question.  But I'm having a problem understanding where to stick the `print()` lines into `function` or code to check them.  I am changing `return` with `print`, etc.  I still can't grasp this part.

I appreciate the help guys!

```
 t = {
    Steve = 4,
    Derek = 1,
    Mike = 3,
    Steph = 8,
    Mary = 15,
    Danny = 10
    }

 function pairsByKeys (t,f) 
    local a = {}

    for x in pairs (t) do
        a[#a + 1] = x
    end

    table.sort(a,f)
    local i = 0
    return function ()
    i = i + 1
    return a[i], t[a[i]]
    end
end

local timer = os.time()
repeat until os.time() > timer + 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pairsByKeys` is implemented as an iterator function (like `pairs` or `ipairs` provided by the standard library), so you can use it in a generic `for` statement like this (using the default compare function):

```
for k,v in pairsByKeys(t) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Output:

```
Danny   10
Derek   1
Mary    15
Mike    3
Steph   8
Steve   4
```

Comment: doh!  Thank you.  Well what am I doing wrong in my code if I wanted them to sort the names by their numerical value?  For example, `Dekek 1` would be first then `Mike 3` would be second, etc.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 The function is named `pairsByKeys` because what it does is to sort by the key. You need a different iterator to sort by value.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 A simple way to do so is to build another table with reverse key-value pairs like `{4 = Steve, 1 = Derek}`, etc. And then use `pairsByKeys` to print this table.

Comment: Very true.  What if there was an instance where the information was retrieved via barcode scanner and a bunch of information came through.  For example, name;age;address;phone.  Now if I was told that they wanted the `t{}` sorted by the age, can you please show me the correct code to sort the above code by their age?

Comment: I just saw "`for name,line in pairsByKeys(lines) do print(name,line) end`" in the PiL which I've read numerous times but obviously COMPLETELY forgot to end my code with above.  I'm a dope.  But my question about the barcode scan still stands above.  I'd like help with fixing my code to sort that table by the values and the names matching up properly with their linked values.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 The general idea is similar, just build an sequence with the values instead of the keys, and you still need the reverse table so that the returned closure can take the key in the original table as the second return value. Why not try it and if there's still some problem, again, I suggest you asking a new question as it's a totally different one from the original question.

Comment: I can sort reverse the table without issue.  I will post another thread with my question and change my `t{}` to incorporate the barcode question.  I appreciate your help as you have cleared things up!  I'll mark your reply as the answer.  Thank you!!!